# How can I access elements inside a table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have html that looks like this,

```
<table id="TableAddresses">
    <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        string 1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="hidden" id='ADDR_843886'
                    <div id='FLAG_843886'>Pending...</div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        string 2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="hidden" id='ADDR_843886'
                    <div id='FLAG_843886'>Pending...</div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
```

How do I get all the strings inside of TableAddresses > tbody >tr > td[0]?

### EDIT:

I was mistaken in tagging jquery. This is actually a asp.net project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to use `querySelectorAll`

```
var td = querySelectorAll("#TableAddresses tbody td")[0];
```

Otherwise you can do

```
var table = document.getElementById("TableAddresses");
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var tr    = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
var td    = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
// etc
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` is not backwards compatible. Just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
document.getElementById('TableAddresses').firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML
```

or with less legacy support:

```
document.querySelector('#TableAddresses td').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` method:

```
var strings = $('#TableAddresses td:first-child').map(function() {
    return $.trim( this.textContent || this.innerText );
}).get(); // ["string 1", "string 2"]
```

Alternatively you can read the [`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement)'s `rows` property:

```
var rows = document.getElementById('TableAddresses').rows, 
    strings = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if ( rows[i].cells[0] ) {
       strings.push( rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML );
    }  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kvyUh/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
var myString = $('#tableAddress td:first').text()
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There's an [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces#Getting_a_text_node_from_the_table) on this topic. In a nutshell, you need to traverse your table with standard means, mostly `getElementsByTagName`, see this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/tevec/2) (look in the console).

```
var table =  document.getElementById("TableAddresses");

var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(rows, function(ele, idx) {
  console.log(ele.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].textContent.trim());
});
```

This snippet traverses each row of your table and outputs the `textContent` of the first `<td>` element. Please note that this will most likely not work out of the box on older IE versions iirc, but nothing that can't be shimmed. ;-)